# Invalid Class String Error when creating C++ Project in Visual Studio 2008 with Vista x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, 64-bit, dllregistration

After going through this Problem (connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=329986) that was related with registry permissions, now again, Visual Studio comes with another error.

I have the same [error](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=331005) as this guy, I have searched all the internet and it seems nobody has resolved it yet.

When I create a C++ Windows Forms Application, and want to see the "Design view" of the the default Form1, it just gives me this error:

Invalid Class String (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDCodeDomProvider.get_CodeDomProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32fReload)
```

I'm sorry if this has nothing to do with programming at all, but if someone has any opinions or comments, I would like to hear it.

Image at img12.imageshack.us/img12/8256/dibujowc.jpg

Sorry for the links, the system don't allow me to put hyperlinks

Comment: Try reinstalling everything. :|

Comment: You were right, reinstall windows again and rigth after Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this hapend to me after i renamed feacp.dll in order to disable intellisense.
However, after re-enabling intellisense, all worked ok.